# How to calculate first occurrence of event, grouped by type?

Tags: mysql, count

Apologies for the basic question, I could not find the answer after searching.

I have a table w/ **team**, **fruit**, **event**, and **timestamp**.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(`team` int, `event` varchar(6), `fruit` varchar(6), 
`timestamp` timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO table1
(`team`, `event`, `fruit`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
(100, 'seen', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:13:00'),
(100, 'bought', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:14:00'),
(100, 'seen', 'banana', '2005-06-20 12:15:00'),
(200, 'seen', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(200, 'seen', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(200, 'seen', 'banana', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(300, 'seen', 'orange', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(300, 'seen', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(300, 'bought', 'orange', '2005-06-20 12:17:00'),
(300, 'bought', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:18:00')
;
```

The goal is to calculate how many teams bought each type of fruit as the first purchase of the day.

This is assuming all data in table is from the same day.

Expected is: apple = 1, orange = 1, banana = 0.

Also, the ideal script would account for null values in the timestamp.

I am a beginner in SQL and this script is not accounting for the teams.

```
select fruit, count((select min(timestamp) from table1
where event = "bought")) 
from table1
group by fruit
;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: @Strawberry Goal is to calculate how many teams bought an apple as their first purchase of the day, how many teams bought a banana... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(activity_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,`team` int
,`event` varchar(6)
,`fruit` varchar(6),
`timestamp` timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO table1
(`team`, `event`, `fruit`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
(100, 'seen', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:13:00'),
(100, 'bought', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:14:00'),
(100, 'seen', 'banana', '2005-06-20 12:15:00'),
(200, 'seen', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(200, 'seen', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(200, 'seen', 'banana', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(300, 'seen', 'orange', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(300, 'seen', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:16:00'),
(300, 'bought', 'orange', '2005-06-20 12:17:00'),
(300, 'bought', 'apple', '2005-06-20 12:18:00')
;
```

> *This is assuming all data in table is from the same day.*

```
SELECT fruit
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM table1 x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(activity_id) activity_id FROM table1 WHERE event = 'bought' GROUP BY team ) y 
    ON y.activity_id = x.activity_id 
 GROUP 
    BY fruit;
+--------+-------+
| fruit  | total |
+--------+-------+
| apple  |     1 |
| orange |     1 |
+--------+-------+
```

Any remaining aspects to this problem can (and, in my view, should) be resolved in application code.

Comment: If my table already exists and does not have the activityID primary key, should I create that field so I can self-join? And should I create it through a process like this: ALTER TABLE... ADD CONSTRAINT... PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, etc)? I'm not sure if just linking together a bunch of columns is enough/good practice to create a unique primary key

Comment: If you don't have some way of uniquely identifying rows, then yes - otherwise, you don't really have a table. Alternatively, if some combination of the existing columns can be guaranteed to be unique, than you can set this combination as PRIMARY instead, and rearrange my query accordingly. My preference would be to opt for a surrogate key in this instance - because it makes the query simpler.

Comment: Does your solution w/ the activity_id assume that the 1st bought fruit's activity ID is the "min" in the set?

Comment: Yes; it seems a reasonable assumption

Comment: The solution works in this scenario, but in an instance where this calculation needs to be made on hundreds of tables, I think I may come across some where the records are not always in time-ascending order. Is there a simple workaround to calculate this using the min(timestamp) instead? Or can I somehow rearrange the entire table in time-ascending order, then run your query to ensure accuracy?

Comment: Yes, you can use min(date) instead- but this comes back to what you can guarantee to be unique